# Why do I keep on getting the error "name 'amazon_soup' is not defined"

Tags: python, html, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

Not sure why I am getting the error?

Comment: You never define amazon_soup.  It is just a local variable in the geturl functions, and it is just a named argument in the getnextpage function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the `amazon_soup` used as an argument to the method and you use it as a variable which is undefined.

It should be:

```
print(getnextpage(geturl(amazon_url)))
```

The `amazon_soup` variable you have declared is local to the method `geturl`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "amazon_soup" is not defined in the current context. In python, and in many other languages, the "level", in which you define a variable matters. This means that you cannot access it from outside of the "level" you are in. In your case, the variable is defined in a function and thus it cannot be access outside of this function. Change the code in line 4 to define amazon_soup at the start, the same way you did for amazon_url. So just add

```
amazon_soup = None
```

at the start of line 4. Then run line 4 and line 5.